autolisp код который меняет содержимое мультивыноски тип которой - блок
Если для обычной выноси я разобрался. Вот код:
    (defun c:КД2 (/ ss i ent textValue) ;рабочая версия. меняет текст в обычной мультивыноске
  "Replace text in selected multi-leaders with the word 'бум'."
  (setq ss (ssget '((0 . "MULTILEADER")))) ; Выбираем все мультивыноски
  (if ss
    (progn
      (setq i 0)
      (repeat (sslength ss)
        (setq ent (ssname ss i))
        (setq textValue (vla-get-TextString (vlax-ename->vla-object ent)))
        (if textValue
          (progn
            (vla-put-TextString (vlax-ename->vla-object ent) "бум")
          )
        )
        (setq i (1+ i))
      )
      (princ "\nText in multi-leaders has been replaced with 'бум'.")
    )
    (princ "\nNo multi-leaders selected.")
  )
  (princ)
)

То для мультивыноски тип блок, не могу понять где прячется содержимое блока из мультивыноски.
